# When Reference Types Are the Same - Arrays

Tags: java, specifications, java-6

I was reading [JavaSE 6 specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html#4.3.4), then I've made a test to solve some doubts.

> Two reference types are the same run-time type if:
>
> - They are both class or both interface types, are defined by the same class loader, and have the same binary name [(§13.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/binaryComp.html#44909), in which case they are sometimes said to be the same run-time class or the same run-time interface.
> - **They are both array types, and their component types are the same run-time type** [(§10)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/arrays.html#27803).

Running the code below...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "" + new String(" ");
        String[] strArr = {str};
        String[] strArr2 = {str};
        System.out.println("strArr == strArr2 : " + (strArr == strArr2));
    }
}
```

...I was expecting the following output:

`strArr == strArr2 : true`

But the current output is:

`strArr == strArr2 : false`

What I'm missing?

Comment: For your code, the JLS only states that `strArr.getClass() == strArr2.getClass()`.

Comment: Are you mixing types and variables? The spex says about the types and your example is about instances. Check the comment above by @dhke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because they're the same type, doesn't mean they're the same object.

When you do

```
String[] strArr = {str};
String[] strArr2 = {str};
```

You're creating two arrays consisting of the same contents, but the arrays themselves are two separate objects.

They are the same type (an array of strings) but they're not the same object (reference X and reference Y). When you say `strArr == strArr2` you're asking whether they are the same object (or instance, if you prefer that terminology).

The JLS you are quoting is at a different level of what you are talking about, it merely says that `String[]` and `String[]` are the same type.

Comment: @JeroenVannel Now I see that this is my misinterpretation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing array references.

Your `strArr` and `strArr2` references are obviously not the same.

You can compare the values by using `Arrays.equals(strArr, strArr2)`.

Your reference comparison would hold true if you initialized `strArr2` with value `strArr`.

Also, comparing the array types (`strArr.getClass() == strArr2.getClass()`) would hold true either way.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing:

Reference type `String[]` is the same as reference type `String[]`, i.e.

```
strArr.getClass() == strArr2.getClass() // true
```

Instance `strArr` of `String[]` is not the same as another instance `strArr2` of the same type, i.e.

```
 strArr == strArr2 // false
```